# Run a File, located in Program Files (x86) from PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, path

I run a Script from C# : Code Looks like this :

```cs
r.Open();
using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(_scriptPath)) {
    ps.Runspace = r;
    ps.Invoke();
    if (ps.HadErrors) {
        List<string> _items = new List<string>();
        var errorMessage = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ErrorRecord err in ps.Streams.Error) {
            errorMessage.AppendLine(err.ToString());
        }

        _items.Add(errorMessage.ToString());

        foreach (var i in _items) {
            MessageBox.Show(i);
        }
    }
}
```

In the script i try to run copy-item, for that i need a path :

Script Path looks like this:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

With a **Write-Host** i got the Path, looks like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\some\random\Folder\File.ps1
```

With the Ps.Streams.Error (in my C# Code) i'm getting following Error Message.

> The term "x86" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> program. Check the spelling of the name, or that the path is correct (if included), and then
> repeat the procedure.

How do I need to write my Code, so Powershell understands my Path?

Comment: @vonPryz edited my post with more information

Comment: @vonPryz updatet my code

Comment: [`AddScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addscript) expects the **content** of a script not the **path** to the script.

Comment: `$ScriptPath = "& '$ScriptPath'"`?

Comment: @iRon thy for your answer. I found out, that the Error occurs when calling the Script from C#. The Script is Fine, its just Powershell, that can't find the 'Program Files (x86)' Path. Means the Script doesn't get executed at all, cause Powershell can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution, or better the Solution :)

My Powershell Script is fine, no error there.
But when running a file from a Path, that has spaces in it, it need special Formation.
Like @iRon wrote.

But not in the script, it is needed it in the C# Code, when calling the PS Script.

My Path looked like this :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\some\random\Folder\File.ps1
```

But should've looked like this to execute :

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\some\random\Folder\File.ps1'
```

Added the "& ' Script '" to the Code :

```
private void executeScripts()
{
        string _dirPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string _sPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_dirPath) + @"\ExecuteScripts\DistributeFiles.ps1";
        string _scriptPath = "& '" + _sPath + "'";   //  <- This is where i added the Formation

        Trace.TraceWarning(_scriptPath);

        using (PowerShellProcessInstance pspi = new PowerShellProcessInstance())
        {
          //rest of the Code in my Post
        }        
}
```

Silly mistake took me quite some hours -.-

But I'm glad I found it. Thanks